# Free Microsoft Excgange mail accounts

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I want to know if there are any free microsoft exchange based email providers available.  Reason is that I want to practice coding solutions with exchange web services at home?

Answer (score 0):

outlook.com mailboxes are Exchange 2019. Not sure if the free mailboxes allow to connect using EWS though.